# Need to find the limit of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(nx)\over n^2}$

Then I need to find 
what is 
$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$, Here $(nx)$ is fractional part of $nx$,By [Weirstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test%E2%80%8E)  The Series Converges Uniformly That I am sure.But what will be the limit?

Comment: As you have x as 0 . won't the expression sum to 0 whatever be n .

Comment: but $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the series converges uniformly, you can switch limit and sum, and get

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \sum \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n^2} = \sum \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n^2} = \sum\frac{0}{n^2} = 0.$$

For a more direct argument, given $\varepsilon >0$, take $N$ such that $$\left |\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {\sin{(nx)}} {n^2} \right |<\varepsilon, \,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Take $\delta$ small enough so that $$|\sin{(Nx)}| <\frac{\varepsilon}{N}, \,\,\, \forall x\in (-\delta, \delta).$$

Then for such $x$,

$$ \left | \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\sin{(nx)}} {n^2} \right | = \left | \sum_{k=1}^N \frac {\sin{(nx)}} {n^2} \right | + \left |\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {\sin{(nx)}} {n^2}\right |< N \frac{\varepsilon}{N} + \varepsilon = 2\varepsilon.$$